# jQuery toggle html not text on click

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make a collapse type of thing using jQuery. Everything works fine except I want the text to toggle between "show more models" and "show less models", and I have no clue what to do. Here's the code:

```
<a id='roll-more' data-toggle="collapse" href=".roll-img2" class="text-dark">
  Show more models <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
</a>

$('#roll-more').toggle(function() {
    $('#roll-more').html('Show less models <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>');
}, function() {
    $('#roll-more').html('Show more models <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>');
});
```

**EDIT**
Thanks for all the responses but I ended up doing this instead. Can't believe it was so simple :)))

```
 $('#roll-more').on('click',function() {
    if($('#roll-more').html() == 'Show more models <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>') {
      $('#roll-more').html('Show less models <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>')
    } else {
      $('#roll-more').html('Show more models <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>')
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or without using toggle function you can use a hidden input to store a value, like 0 or 1 to decide what to see based on this value. Here an example:

```js
$('#roll-more').click(function() {
  if($("#toggle").val()==1){
     $('#roll-more').html('Show less models <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>');
      $('#toggle').val(0);
      }
      else{
      $('#roll-more').html('Show more models <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>');  
       $('#toggle').val(1);
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="toggle" type="hidden" value="1"/>
<a id='roll-more' data-toggle="collapse" class="text-dark">
  Show more models <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset = "UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv = "X-UA-Compatible" content = "IE = edge,chrome = 1">
      <title>Hello World</title>
      <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>  

   </head>

   <body>
  <span id='roll-more' class="text-dark" style="color:blue;cursor: pointer ">
  Show more models <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
</span><br/>
<span id="contanincll" style="display: none">
This is loreipus content. This is loreipus content. This is loreipus content. This is loreipus content. 

</span>


   </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){


$('#roll-more').on('click',function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
    $(this).html('Show less models <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>');
    $("#contanincll").toggle();
}, function() {
    $(this).html('Show more models <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>');
     $("#contanincll").toggle();
});
});
  </script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```js
$('#roll-more').click(function() {
  var link = $(this);
  $('.text').toggle('fast', function() {
      if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
      link.text('Show less models');
      } else { 
      link.text('Show more models');
     }
  });
});
```

```css
.text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id='roll-more' data-toggle="collapse" href="#roll-img2" class="text-dark">
  Show more models <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
</a>

<div class="text">
  <p>text</p>
</div>
```